# I need to make the first column a specific width using FlexBox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Codepen https://codepen.io/victoreugen2002/pen/VwPVqpm

```
.article-item {
    display: flex;
}
.first-column {
  width: 270px;
}
```

The first column is not 270px width and I need to make it 270px width and the other column to take the space that is left.

Answer (score 0):

One Odd thing I found on your fiddle is .first-column is declared at css while its .first-col at the html markup. Anyway its quite easy fix honestly

```
.article-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.first-col {
  min-width: 270px;
}
```

Of course if you feel like the elements inside .first-col can have more than the width. you can add   `max-width: 270px;` to compensate for that.

If you want to be fancy you can also use `flex-grow` with a defined `flex-basis`

Answer (score 0):

`.first-column { flex: 0 0 270px; }`

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two places.

First, edit `class` name from `first-column` to `first-col`:

Then You should use the `flex` or `flex-basis` property rather than `width`. [Read more on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```
.first-col {
  flex: 0 0 270px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

An example:

```css
.article-item {
    display: flex;
}

.first-col {
  flex: 0 0 270px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
Content<div class="article-item">
    <div class="first-col">
    First Column
    </div>                  
    <div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies erat quam, eget lobortis est convallis a. Suspendisse vitae blandit nibh, ac convallis mi. Mauris sit amet velit sed purus egestas tristique. Aenean imperdiet finibus mauris, eget tristique tellus bibendum in. Nulla facilisis risus feugiat mi tempor, nec ultrices turpis elementum. Nulla vehicula sit amet dui sit amet egestas. Proin aliquam semper pretium. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas id magna vitae eros rutrum blandit. Suspendisse consectetur risus non diam sagittis, et ullamcorper ipsum commodo. Maecenas maximus velit purus, sed hendrerit est interdum eu. Etiam nec nisi arcu.

Phasellus id nulla commodo, hendrerit quam vulputate, tempus lectus. Vestibulum venenatis nisi ac est efficitur, id sollicitudin orci vestibulum. Proin luctus, nulla sed volutpat sagittis, mi dui molestie urna, non tincidunt nisi libero quis nulla. Mauris porttitor ultricies augue, eu bibendum lorem tincidunt vel. Vestibulum ante sapien, accumsan in dui at, dapibus iaculis urna. Suspendisse malesuada erat eget blandit porta. Vivamus tempor venenatis commodo. Donec at rutrum urna, at fringilla nulla. Nullam maximus cursus lacus vitae eleifend.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```